# Jquery of a HTML Input Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".email-form").hide();
  $(".name-form").hide();
  $(".btn-form").hide();
})
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn-adddata").click(function(){
    $(".email-form").show();
    $(".name-form").show();
    $(".btn-form").show();
    $(this).hide();
    $(".btn-confirm").click(function(){
      email = $(".email-input").val();
      name = $(".name-input").val();
      $(".email-input").val()="";
      $(".name-input").val()="";
      $(".email-form").hide();
      $(".name-form").hide();
      $(".btn-form").hide();
      $(".btn-adddata").show();
    });
    $(".btn-cancel").click(function(){
      $(".email-form").hide();
      $(".name-form").hide();
      $(".btn-form").hide();
      $(".btn-adddata").show();
    })
  })
})
```

Details of my Webpage

1. Initially, there will only be `.btn-adddata` button in the webpage.
2. When the user clicks `.btn-adddata` button, it will be hidden and three hidden forms appear in 
      the browser. First form contains only a `fieldset` which further contains an input box. Same is the case with the second form. While the third form contains two buttons `.btn-confirm` and `.btn-cancel`.
3. On clicking `.btn-cancel`, the page should be back to it's original state.
4. On clicking `.btn-confirm`, the page should come back to it's original state except that the user entered values in the input fields are stored in a variable.
   But actually nothing was happening when I am clicking `.btn-confirm` button.
   I couldn't figure out what's going on. 
   Some one please figure out the error for me.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: First look  `-input").val()=""` should be `-input").val("")` not equals

Comment: Yeah, I found it. But after clicking ```.btn-confirm``` when I again click ```.btn-adddata```,  previous email entered is retrieved to the email field but not the name. What could be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should hide the form in your HTML using inline CSS so that they don't flash and disappear.

`<form style="display; none">`

Then you don't need to hide them in `$(document).ready(...)`.

Secondly, you have a mistake in your event handler. You need add 3 click handlers, but instead, you have only one click handler, which adds two more click handlers every time the first button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn-adddata").click(function(){
    // insert: code to show all forms and hide this button
  }); // <-- you're missing this


  $(".btn-confirm").click(function(){
    // insert: code to get values
    // insert: code to set values to ''
    // e.g. $(...).val("");
  });

  $(".btn-cancel").click(function(){
     // insert: code for cancel button
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** First look `-input").val()=""` should be `-input").val("")` not equals

**2nd:** Personally I don't prefer events inside event

**3rd:** You can combine selectors `$(".class1 , .class2 , #id1 , #id2 , ....")`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var If_adddata = false; // condition to stop confirm and cancel buttons to work until the adddata click first
  $(".email-form , .name-form , .btn-form").hide();
  // adddata click
  $(".btn-adddata").click(function(){
    $(".email-form , .name-form , .btn-form").show();
    $(this).hide();
    If_adddata = true;
  });
  // confirm click
  $(".btn-confirm").click(function(){
    if(If_adddata === true){
      var email = $(".email-input").val(),
          name = $(".name-input").val();
      $(".email-input , .name-input").val("");
      $(".email-form , .name-form , .btn-form").hide();
      $(".btn-adddata").show();
    }
  });
  // cancel click
  $(".btn-cancel").click(function(){
    if(If_adddata === true){
      $(".email-form , .name-form , .btn-form").hide();
      $(".btn-adddata").show();
    }
  })
})
```